# how i can have a dynamically title in a book with XSLT and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt, xpath

I have this `xml` :

```
<quran>
    <row>
        <WID>10</WID>
        <word>بسم</word>
        <SID>1</SID>
        <Ayeh>0</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>4556</ParentID>
        <Page>1</Page>
        <Joint>1</Joint>
        <SName>فاتحه</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>11</WID>
        <word>الله</word>
        <SID>1</SID>
        <Ayeh>0</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>3565</ParentID>
        <Page>1</Page>
        <Joint>1</Joint>
        <SName>فاتحه</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>12</WID>
        <word>الرحمن</word>
        <SID>1</SID>
        <Ayeh>0</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>2876</ParentID>
        <Page>1</Page>
        <Joint>1</Joint>
        <SName>فاتحه</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>14</WID>
        <word>الْحَمْدُ</word>
        <SID>1</SID>
        <Ayeh>2</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>2732</ParentID>
        <Page>1</Page>
        <Joint>1</Joint>
        <SName>فاتحه</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>15</WID>
        <word>للّهِ</word>
        <SID>1</SID>
        <Ayeh>2</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>12105</ParentID>
        <Page>1</Page>
        <Joint>1</Joint>
        <SName>فاتحه</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>5618</WID>
        <word>بسم</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ayeh>0</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>4556</ParentID>
        <Page>2</Page>
        <Joint>2</Joint>
        <SName>بقره</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>5619</WID>
        <word>الله</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ayeh>0</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>3565</ParentID>
        <Page>2</Page>
        <Joint>2</Joint>
        <SName>بقره</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>5620</WID>
        <word>الرحمن</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ayeh>0</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>2876</ParentID>
        <Page>2</Page>
        <Joint>2</Joint>
        <SName>بقره</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>4784</WID>
        <word>الم</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ayeh>1</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>3567</ParentID>
        <Page>2</Page>
        <Joint>2</Joint>
        <SName>بقره</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>5105</WID>
        <word>ذَلِكَ</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ayeh>2</Ayeh>
        <Joze>1</Joze>
        <Hezb>1</Hezb>
        <ParentID>7234</ParentID>
        <Page>2</Page>
        <Joint>2</Joint>
        <SName>بقره</SName>
    </row>
    <quran>
```

I need insert the `<SName>` before tags `<Ayeh>` that is `<Ayeh>0</Ayeh>` .
i write a jquery code but i dont know how i use xslt in jquery ?(below code Dont work)

```
$('.quranText .ayaNumber').each(function(){
    if($.trim($(this).text())=='﴿0﴾')
       $(this).closest('.aya').prepend('<div class="suraHeaderFrame">'
                    +'<div class="suraHeaderText">'+ 

                                        <xsl:for-each-group select="//row[./Page/text()=$page]" group-by="Page">
                                            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="SID">
                                                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="concat(Page,SID)">
                                                <xsl:choose > 
                                                     <xsl:when test = "./Ayeh = 1 or ./Ayeh = 0" >  
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="SName"/>
                                                        </xsl:when>
                                                  </xsl:choose>
                                                </xsl:for-each-group>
                                            </xsl:for-each-group>
                                        </xsl:for-each-group>

 +'</div>'
                +'</div>');
});
```

I should say that often in a one page is alot of `<Ayeh>0</Ayeh>`.
I am writing a site same this : http://tanzil.net/#109:1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you should be using parseXML http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

```
var xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?><quran><row><WID>10</WID><word>بسم</word><SID>1</SID><Ayeh>0</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>4556</ParentID><Page>1</Page><Joint>1</Joint><SName>فاتحه</SName></row><row><WID>11</WID><word>الله</word><SID>1</SID><Ayeh>0</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>3565</ParentID><Page>1</Page><Joint>1</Joint><SName>فاتحه</SName></row><row><WID>12</WID><word>الرحمن</word><SID>1</SID><Ayeh>0</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>2876</ParentID><Page>1</Page><Joint>1</Joint><SName>فاتحه</SName></row><row><WID>14</WID><word>الْحَمْدُ</word><SID>1</SID><Ayeh>2</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>2732</ParentID><Page>1</Page><Joint>1</Joint><SName>فاتحه</SName></row><row><WID>15</WID><word>للّهِ</word><SID>1</SID><Ayeh>2</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>12105</ParentID><Page>1</Page><Joint>1</Joint><SName>فاتحه</SName></row><row><WID>5618</WID><word>بسم</word><SID>2</SID><Ayeh>0</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>4556</ParentID><Page>2</Page><Joint>2</Joint><SName>بقره</SName></row><row><WID>5619</WID><word>الله</word><SID>2</SID><Ayeh>0</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>3565</ParentID><Page>2</Page><Joint>2</Joint><SName>بقره</SName></row><row><WID>5620</WID><word>الرحمن</word><SID>2</SID><Ayeh>0</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>2876</ParentID><Page>2</Page><Joint>2</Joint><SName>بقره</SName></row><row><WID>4784</WID><word>الم</word><SID>2</SID><Ayeh>1</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>3567</ParentID><Page>2</Page><Joint>2</Joint><SName>بقره</SName></row><row><WID>5105</WID><word>ذَلِكَ</word><SID>2</SID><Ayeh>2</Ayeh><Joze>1</Joze><Hezb>1</Hezb><ParentID>7234</ParentID><Page>2</Page><Joint>2</Joint><SName>بقره</SName></row></quran>"
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$xml.find( "SName" ).each(function(){
    $(this).siblings('Ayeh').before($(this));
})
```

That will move the SName node before its sibling Ayeh node. $xml[0] will then be the xml document you can use or alternatively you can append the jQuery object $xml to your div.

Comment: Very very thanks my friend.with your response i get an other response.